# How To Keep Records in Order from Derived Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a SQL table from a remote DB2 table. There may be multiple updates for the same record but I need the updates to happen in the order they are in in the DB2 table. You can not use Order By on a derived table. I have tried several different options to try to get this to work, but the updates still do not happen in order.

For example:

- Change 1 - CUSTOMER NAME = ABCX
- Change 2 - CUSTOMER NAME = ABC

After I run the query, the customer name is ABCX when it should be ABC.

I truly do not know what else to try. I've tried temp tables (still derived table), creating a concatenated field with date and time fields, sub-select, row_number() over(order by date, time) and many other things. I'd like to keep it in order by the date and time fields in the remote table.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Here is the basic code I have:

```
        SET
            A.CUSRID = B.RECORD_ID,
            A.CUSSTS = B.ACTIVE_CODE,
            A.CUSCOM = B.COMPANY_NUMBER,
            A.CUSMNM = B.CUSTOMER_NAME,
            A.CUSAD1 = B.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1,
            A.CUSAD2 = B.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_2,
            A.CUSAD3 = B.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_3,
            A.CUSZIP = B.CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE,
            A.CUSZPE = B.CUSZPE_NOT_USED,
            A.CUSSTC = B.CUSTOMER_STATE,
            A.CUSARA = B.CUSTOMER_AREA_CODE,
            A.CUSPHN = B.CUSTOMER_PHONE,
            A.CUSB17 = B.CUSB17_NOT_USED,
            A.CUSTMT = B.STATEMENT_PRINT_CODE,
            A.CUSCRL = B.CREDIT_LIMIT,
            A.CUSCRC = B.CREDIT_CODE,
            A.CUSMCD = B.CUSMCD_NOT_USED,
            A.CUSTX1 = B.TAX_RATE_1,
            A.CUSTX2 = B.TAX_RATE_2,
            A.CUSTXC = B.TAX_RATE,
            A.CUSTXE = B.TAX_EXEMPT_ID,
            A.CUSB48 = B.CUSB48_NOT_USED,
            A.CUSMDT = B.MAINTENANCE_DATE,
            A.CUSB20 = B.CUSB20_NOT_USED,
            A.CSSRCH = B.SEARCH_FIELD,
            A.CUSBRN = B.BRANCH_ID,
            A.CUSDST = B.DISTRIBUTOR_NUMBER,
            A.CUSB28 = B.CUSB28_NOT_USED
    FROM 
        dbo.mcusmas A 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                RECORD_ID,
                ACTIVE_CODE,
                COMPANY_NUMBER,
                CUSTOMER_NUMBER,
                CUSTOMER_NAME,
                CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_1,
                CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_2,
                CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_3,
                CUSTOMER_ZIP_CODE,
                CUSZPE_NOT_USED,
                CUSTOMER_STATE,
                CUSTOMER_AREA_CODE,
                CUSTOMER_PHONE,
                CUSB17_NOT_USED,
                STATEMENT_PRINT_CODE,
                CREDIT_LIMIT,
                CREDIT_CODE,
                CUSMCD_NOT_USED,
                TAX_RATE_1,
                TAX_RATE_2,
                TAX_RATE,
                TAX_EXEMPT_ID,
                CUSB48_NOT_USED,
                MAINTENANCE_DATE,
                CUSB20_NOT_USED,
                SEARCH_FIELD,
                BRANCH_ID,
                DISTRIBUTOR_NUMBER,
                CUSB28_NOT_USED,
            FROM remoteserver.MCUSMASPLG
            WHERE Event_State_ID = '*New' AND SENT_TO_DATA_WAREHOUSE = 'N'
        ) B
        ON A.CUSMNB = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

Comment: You are approaching it from the wrong direction; You should be updating each row only once and getting the most recent value from the source, eg the row with the max date, max Id etc

Comment: So then I will need to run the query multiple times to get all of the updates when there are multiple updates for the same row?

Comment: I don't think you fully understand the concepts underpinning the RDBMS model. What I think you are trying to do is a fairly common scenario, if you add details of your tables and sample data & expected results to your question it will be easier for someone to correctly advise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "change 1" or "change 2".  There are only rows and SQL Server arbitrarily ends up using one of them.  If you want to control the rows, you should select the one you want in advance:

```
FROM dbo.mcusmas A JOIN
     (SELECT B.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_NUMBER ORDER BY <ordering col>) as seqnum
      FROM remoteserver.MCUSMASPLG
      WHERE Event_State_ID = '*New' AND
            SENT_TO_DATA_WAREHOUSE = 'N'
     ) B
     ON A.CUSMNB = B.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

I don't know how you are determining which row is the right one.  Presumably, some column has this information and you can use it in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you, but I made the example simplified I guess...

When I said change 1, it is in the remote file first, it may have other columns with changes as well so that update needs to be applied first.

Change 2 may change only one of the columns from the same record, so I need the changes that occurred in both records, not just the last one. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Elonna . . . That is not how `update` works.  It updates based on *one* matching row.  Any matching row.

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to understand. Thank you. I think this needs to be done in a program. My manager told me to use queries, but do not think he realized there may be multiple changes. Thank you for your response.